# Only one feature shown at one location with GeoJSON

Tags: geojson

Consider the [GeoJSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) here:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Place": "KECK SENG TOWER",
        "Name": "FOO"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          103.849001802657,
          1.28022346789656
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Place": "KECK SENG TOWER",
        "Name": "BAR"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          103.849001802657,
          1.28022346789656
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There are two businesses "FOO" & "BAR" in the same building. I want to be able to see both businesses on a map.

When rendered by say Github https://gist.github.com/kaihendry/8b9847d1325d6ec1b694652d25c2ba3a only "BAR" shows up. Same with the https://geojsonlint.com/

So "FOO" disappears, which is very misleading! How does one typically work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The features have the exact same coordinates i.e. they are on top of each other.

To display both at the same time you can give them slightly different coordinates, play with their opacity or give the markers a different size.

You can also look for clustering plugins that visually group markers and allow the use to click to expand them.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same building. Can't be that unusual a scenario.

Comment: It's not unusual but the solution is non-trivial. Ideally the markers will be put on the spot where that business resides in the building. But, who will do that (you'd need an indoor map and someone/something that knows where on that map each business sits). What happens if two businesses have the same location but are situated on a different floor? They'll overlap yet again.

Comment: Check out this map/app: https://bagviewer.kadaster.nl/lvbag/bag-viewer/#?searchQuery=amsterdam&resultOffset=0&objectId=0363100012182799&geometry.x=122010.824&geometry.y=487324.598&zoomlevel=7&detailsObjectId= where they (randomly?) distribute the addresses within a building. Note: those are not the real locations of the addresses within the building.